# Setting One Drive Sync Folders through Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, onedrive-for-business

It it possible to set certain folders (such as Documents/Downloads) to automatically sync on One Drive (sync client is installed on local machines) through Group Policy?  Or is this something that needs to be done individually on a machine to machine basis?

Or is there a better way to handle this kind of issue?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does offer ADML policies for OneDrive with the ability to silently sign them in with their domain credentials. You can then setup policy to silently move known folders into OneDrive

Adding ADML policies to your domain
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/use-group-policy

Sign users silently into OneDrive
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/use-group-policy#SilentAccountConfig

Silently move Windows known folders to OneDrive
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/use-group-policy#KFMOptInNoWizard